# Call Javascript Function on remote server

Tags: javascript, function, server

We have some website javascript tracking code, similar to google analytics.

We have written a very large function to perform extra tracking, but we don't want to put this code onto the websites.
We want to store it on our server, so we can make global changes.

If the code is in the file `c:\production\functions\forms.js`,

How do I call it from the code on the website ??

The code is in the header tag of the website as its from MATOMO analytics
I would like to put in a line of code in at this point to call the function to when the web page loads

sample code below and where I would like to call the function

```html
    <!-- Matomo -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _paq = window._paq || [];

   *** CALL FUNCTION HERE ***


      _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
      _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
      (function() {
        var u="https://matomo.cloud/";
        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', '62']);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
      })();
    </script>
    <!-- End Matomo Code -->
```

The file is stored on an Azure server

Comment: Could you provide information on what you've tried so far and ask a more specific question?

Comment: You mean you want to execute that code in the browser? Or you want web clients to remotely invoke that code to run on the server? I would bet for the former, but it is not super clear.

Comment: Are you talking execution or source control?

Comment: II want to invoke the function from the web browser when the web page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

In a past project. We expose this resource by micro-service.

I think this may be the solution. Expose the method with a micro-service.

Full Example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zqmuwu-example-traking?file=index.js

This would be your micro service that loads your file with your method and through an object you deliver the data that your method needs to work.

```js
const app = require('express')();
const forms = require('./forms.js');

app.get('/traking', (req, res) => {
  forms(req.query);
  return res.status(201).send('ok');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Later from your front you can load a fetch to execute your method.

Example.

```js
function traking(params = {}) {
  var url = new URL("https://geo.example.org/api");

  Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]));

  fetch(url);
}
```

This is used on your button or link.

```html
<button onclick="traking({a:3})">Click</button>
```